# Photoshop Composite: Glass Reflection

Tags: adobe-photoshop, camera

I'm trying to make a composite where the camera is facing the glass but focused on the reflection of the city or what is behind the camera. Are there any ways to make this more realistic?

[image: example]

Answer (score 1):

You might want to add the environment where your subject is standing. It may add realism to your work.

Comment: +1 for seeing the most obvious problem.. The image is ambiquous - impossible to decide is the camera outdoors or indoors.  A  camera with short focal range can can have enough field of depth to make all sharp.  A small part of window frame would solve the ambiquity.

Answer (score 0):

A real photograph taken in such dark conditions would have a wide aperture, which means less depth of field. This implies that the window (and the raindrops) would definitely be unfocused, and possibly also the subject in the reflection. You can play with the focus of the subject so it at least suggests who we should see.

Another option would be to have the subject in focus, but the window again unfocused, and the city somewhat defocused.

There is water on the window, but the city isn't glistening wet.

There are some flares that don't quite make sense here. Are they reflections of the scene behind the camera? Were they part of the "wet window" image? There isn't any light source in the city image that would warrant these flares.

Comment: Clearly the girl sneezed and that's why the window is wet. :) KIDDING!